# WordPress database error: [Unknown column 'wp_learndash_pro_quiz_question' in 'where clause'] when i uploading a excel file using a plugin

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am getting this error while uploading a excel file using a plugin excel to learndash.

It's working fine after uploading but some time it fetching duplicate data.

> WordPress database error: [Unknown column 'wp_learndash_pro_quiz_question' in 'where clause'] SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = wp_learndash_pro_quiz_question AND column_name = 'name'
>
> WordPress database error: [Duplicate column name 'name'] ALTER TABLE wp_learndash_pro_quiz_question ADD name VARCHAR(550) NOT NULL

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem about code, it wants to verify column name exists in wp_learndash_pro_quiz_question table.
If does not exist add column.

The problem is that query

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = wp_learndash_pro_quiz_question AND column_name = 'name'
```

should be

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'wp_learndash_pro_quiz_question' AND column_name = 'name'
```

Quotes are missing.